# I wrote this code but my output is not in 2D as it should have been, and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python

I wrote my code completely, but I'm not getting the expected output from the question. When I put in my values they are not in a 2D list for some reason.

**Functions:**

```
def matrix_rotate_right(a):

    b = []

    for i in range(len(a[0])):
        b.append([])
        for j in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
            b[i].append(a[j][i])

    return b
```

**t01.py**

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
b = matrix_rotate_right(a)
print(b)
```

**the question:**

```
Write and test the following function:

def matrix_rotate_right(a):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns a copy of a 2D matrix rotated to the right.
    a must be unchanged.
    Use: b = matrix_rotate_right(a)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        a - a 2D list of values (2d list of int/float)
    Returns:
        b - the rotated 2D list of values (2D list of int/float)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
Add this function to the PyDev module functions.py. Test it from t01.py.
```

**A sample run:**

```
Given the following 2D matrix:

 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
10 11 12
Rotating it to the right produces the following matrix:

10  7  4  1
11  8  5  2
12  9  6  3
```

**The output I'm getting:**

```
[[10, 7, 4, 1], [11, 8, 5, 2], [12, 9, 6, 3]]
```

Comment: Your task is just to rotate the matrix. How it prints is irrelevant. Your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Your4 function  doeswhat you wanted.

You need only to format the output

```
def matrix_rotate_right(a):

    b = []

    for i in range(len(a[0])):
        b.append([])
        for j in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
            b[i].append(a[j][i])

    return b
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
b = matrix_rotate_right(a)
for tuple in b:
    print(format(' '.join(map(str,tuple))))
```